# Dereference array of hashes in perl. experimental warning

Tags: perl

I am getting a warning when accessing my array. This is probably a unperl way to loop but I am teaching myself perl and I am trying different scenarios.  I can loop over the `%user` but didn't know how to loop over the array hash ref?

```
my %user;
$user{mike}{emp_id} = 1;
$user{john}{emp_id} = 2;
my @user = \%user;

foreach my $value_hash (@users)
{
   #error line
   foreach my $key (keys $value_hash) 
   { 
      foreach my $id (keys %{ $users{$key} }) 
      {
         print "name: $key\t$id: $users{$key}{$id}\n";
      }
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Tip: `foreach my $value_hash (@users)` makes no sense. `@users` always contains exactly one value, so you could just as easily use `my $value_hash = \%user;`. But why create a reference at all?

Comment: *I am getting a warning when accessing my array* A tip for the future. It's always worth telling exactly what warning message you see.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I am just trying different things in perl.  I don't use it often but I have to maintain some code and I came across that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keys EXPR` was an experiemental feature that has already been abandoned and removed.

```
$ 5.22t/bin/perl -e'my $h = {}; keys $h;'
keys on reference is experimental at -e line 1.

$ 5.24t/bin/perl -e'my $h = {}; keys $h;'
Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden at -e line 1.
```

The proper ways to use `keys` is

```
keys HASH
keys ARRAY
```

Replace

```
keys $value_hash
```

with

```
keys %$value_hash
```

or

```
keys %{ $value_hash }
```

You already used it correctly the second time around.